# Unable to read file with Imagick and laravel on docker container

Tags: laravel, docker, imagemagick, imagick, laradock

I'm an issue on reading a PDF file with Imagick on Laravel using Laradock (docker).

This is my code:

```
$imagick = new Imagick();
$imagick->readImage(url('storage/'.$file->name).'[0]');

$imgFile = str_replace(".pdf",".jpg",$file->name);

$saveImagePath = public_path($imgFile);
$imagick->writeImages($saveImagePath, true);
$image = $saveImagePath;
```

My file is located into `storage/app/public/1/documents/filename.pdf` and I created a symbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`.

When I try to execute the code I get this error message:

```
ImagickException
Failed to read the file
```

And the error is marked on line `$imagick->readImage(url('storage/'.$file->name).'[0]');`

Any idea?

I already installed IMAGEMAGICK and GHOSTSCRIPT on workspace and php_fpm container and I checked it with `phpinfo();`.

I also tried to print the value of `url('storage/'.$file->name)` and open it in a browser and the pdf file can be opened.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll need `ghostscript` installed if you want to read PDFs.

Comment: @MarkSetchell sorry I forgot to tell that it was also installed. I updated the main thread.

Comment: Try passing a physical file path to readImage() method instead of url

Comment: @KhangTran I tried your solution and the error changed to this one: 
`unable to open image '/var/www/project/storage/app/1/documents/13/filename.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2924`

Comment: Try the path: /var/www/project/storage/app/public/1/documents/filename.pdf. Make sure you pass the right path

Comment: @KhangTran this solved the path issue (I wrote it without get with laravel command. How can I get it and not the symbolic link?). But I get this error now: `attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy 'PDF' @ error/constitute.c/IsCoderAuthorized/421`

Comment: Search the error on google, I believe you can find the answer